# Problem in getting values from an array

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

```
var xml:XML;
var urlL:URLLoader =  new URLLoader();
var xmlArray:Array = new Array();
var i:uint;

urlL.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlL.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedAction);
urlL.load(new URLRequest("list.xml"));
function onLoadedAction(e:Event):void {
    try {
        xml = new XML(e.target.data);
        xml.ignoreWhitespace = true;
        for (i = 0; i<xml.video.length(); i++) {
            xmlArray.push(xml.video.path[i]);
            //trace(xmlArray[i]);
        }
    } catch (e:Error) {
        trace(e.message);
    }
}
trace(xmlArray[0]);
```

This is my code. 
When I am tracing the 0 th index value from the array, I am getting "undefined" in the output panel.

What is the bug?

Comment: you need to use an IOErrorEvent listener for the loader instead of a try/catch block in the complete handler - if the file can't be loaded the complete handler isn't going to be called.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
- <videos>
- <video>
  <path>video1.flv</path> 
  </video>
- <video>
  <path>video2.flv</path> 
  </video>
- <video>
  <path>video3.flv</path> 
  </video>
- <video>
  <path>video4.flv</path> 
  </video>
  </videos>

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 :  I found the answer. I have assigned the values locally, so that I can't access globally. Matter of "variable scope".

Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: my comment wasn't addressing your question, which is why i commented here instead of posting an answer.  i'm glad you found a solution to your problem, but if you want to avoid potential problems in the future, you should really add an IOErrorEvent listener to your URLLoader instance instead of relying on a try/catch block in the complete handler.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 : Thanks for your passion towards as3.

Comment: i've posted some code for you to look at so there's no confusion.  i hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code provided, it looks as though you're attempting to trace the value before the XML has a chance to completely load (outside of the onLoadedAction function). If you move your trace to the end (inside) of the onLoadedAction function, you should see a result.

Comment: s, I could see that. But I have declare the array, outside of the function. So I can access right?

Comment: Yes. You can access variables that are declared outside of your functions. However, you can't access a variable (from outside of the function) that has been declared inside of a function. Check out -  [variable scope](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Imports
import flash.errors.IOError;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

//Variables
var xml:XML;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlArray:Array = new Array();

//Load XML
xmlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, xmlLoaderErrorEventHandler);
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlCompleteEventHandler);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("list.xml"));

//XML Loader Error Event Handler
function xmlLoaderErrorEventHandler(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
     throw new IOError(evt.text);
}

//XML Complete Event Handler
function xmlCompleteEventHandler(evt:Event):void
{
     evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, xmlLoaderErrorEventHandler);
     evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlCompleteEventHandler);

     xml = new XML(evt.currentTarget.data);

     for each  (var element:XML in xml.video.path)
               xmlArray.push(element);

     trace(xmlArray);
}
```

Comment: Gr8... But I don't need package level programming right now... I am looking for play less than 10 videos.

Comment: the code above was written to work in the Actions panel in Flash Professional CS5.

Comment: you have imported everything, so that I thought package level programming.for timeline level we don't need to import right?.. simple confusion.

Comment: humm... i'm not sure about that since i never write frame scripts.  however, when writing code in the Actions panel of Flash Professional CS5, automatic importing does happen, i'm just not sure if it's required or not in which case having it or not having it wouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: I am using CS3 only. 
  Do u know about eventDispatcher  class?

Comment: it will work in CS3.  you could probably just remove the imports.  if there is an compile error you may have to rewrite them.  here is a link to the AS3 documentation:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
xmlArray.push(xml.video.path[i]);
```

To this:

```
xmlArray.push(xml.video..path[i]);
```